# Weighted correlation

Tags: c, correlation, weighted

I have two arrays of floats, and want to calculate the weighted correlation, meaning that I want some of my data to have lower weight than others.

```
      X          Y        w
   2.02382   6.00298   0.43873
   3.94601   6.41983   0.36818
   3.76877   4.55656   0.49836
   3.68307   6.46925   0.95965
   3.09073   4.57723   0.88889
   2.56690   2.70020   0.72812
   3.35469   6.76874   0.26863
   3.88722   5.23205   0.77492
   3.29389   3.50355   0.79567
   3.80725   3.18414   0.82439
```

So, I want correlation between X, and Y regarding the weights w.
My problem is mainly a theory problem, but at the end I want to implement it in C.

Comment: Are you trying to reinvent [robust regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robust_regression)?

Comment: I just want to learn its theory more deeply. Too bad I can't upload the scatter-plot of my data here to support why I need to weight some of the data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main idea is that whenever you see E(...) you replace 1/n with w/sum(w).

Theory:

Corr(X,Y) = E( (X - E(X))*(Y - E(Y) ) / SD(X)SD(Y) ;

So first calculate E(X) and E(Y).

E(X) = (2.02382 * .43873 + ... + 3.80725*.82439) / (.43873+...+.82439) = 3.368

E(Y) = [same weighted average idea] = 4.705

sd(X) = sqrt( var(X) ) =  sqrt( E( (X-E(X))^2 ) ) = sqrt( ( (.43873)*(2.02382-3.368)^2 + ... + (.82439)*(3.80725-3.368)^2 ) / (.43873+...+.82439) ) = sqrt(0.3054023) = 0.5526321

sd(Y) = [same weighted average idea] = sqrt(1.860124) =  1.363863

corr(x,y) = ( (.43873)*(2.02382-3.368)(6.00298-4.705)+...+(.82439)*(3.80725-3.368)(3.18414-4.705) ) / ( (.43873+...+.82439)*(.5526)*(1.3634) ) = 0.2085651

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, this is more like weighted averaging! I think some fuzzy solution would work